# Parcelable object being received null via notification but works between activites

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have an Intent Service called ParserService which performs some task and creates an object(ArtistInfo) which is parcelable. Then it checks if the app is in foreground. If it is then it sends a broadcast with the parcelable object in the intent extras. This broadcast is received by the activity MainActivity.java which then creates an intent with the same object and launches an activity called ListSongsActivity where the parcelable object is successfully received.

But if the app is not in foreground then the ParserService sends a notification which has the same intent as that of a broadcast. But when the ListSongsActivity is being launched through the notification the parcelable object(ArtistInfo) this time is null. And I am also passing a string in the intent. This string is being received correctly via the notification intent but the parcelable object is null.

Please find the relevant code snippets below.

Broadcast and notification code from the ParserService:

```
if (CommonUtils.appInForeground(getApplicationContext())) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent(): Sending success broadcast.");
                sendBroadcast(createSuccessIntent(artistInfo));
            } else {
                // TODO: 10-10-2018 tapping on notification does nothing!!
                Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent(): Sending success notification.");
                String body = "Parsing complete for the url: " + url;
                Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListSongsActivity.class);
                notifyIntent.putExtra(Constants.MUSIC_SITE, siteName);
                notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable(Constants.PARSED_ARTIST_INFO, artistInfo);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                CommonUtils.sendNotification(getApplicationContext(), Constants.LIST_SONGS_NOTIFICATION_TITLE
                        , body, Constants.LIST_SONGS_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, notifyIntent,
                        Constants.LIST_SONGS_NOTIFICATION_ID, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
            }

private Intent createSuccessIntent(ArtistInfo artistInfo) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Constants.PARSE_SUCCESS_ACTION_KEY);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(Constants.PARSE_SUCCESS_MESSAGE_KEY, artistInfo);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    return intent;
}
```

Broadcast Received in a fragment of the MainActivity:

```
private class ParserBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ParserBroadcastReceiver, onReceive()");
        String parseResult = intent.getAction();
        if (parseResult == null || parseResult.equals(Constants.EMPTY_STRING)) {
            return;
        }
        switch (parseResult) {
            case Constants.PARSE_SUCCESS_ACTION_KEY:
                ArtistInfo artistInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.PARSE_SUCCESS_MESSAGE_KEY);
                Log.d(TAG, "ParserBroadcastReceiver, onReceive() PARSE_SUCCESS_ACTION_KEY, artistInfo: "
                        + artistInfo.toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "site: " + musicSite);
                createIntentAndDelegateActivity(artistInfo);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void createIntentAndDelegateActivity(ArtistInfo artistInfo) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createIntentAndDelegateActivity()");
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ListSongsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.MUSIC_SITE, musicSite);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(Constants.PARSED_ARTIST_INFO, artistInfo);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

sendNotification in CommonUtils:

```
public static void sendNotification(Context context, String title, String body,
                                    String channelId, Intent intent, Integer id, Integer iconResourceId) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (notificationManager == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "sendNotification(): noti manager null!!");
        return;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                Constants.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription(Constants.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(Constants.PENDING_INTENT_DEFAULT_REQ_CODE,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId);
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setContentText(body);
    builder.setSmallIcon(iconResourceId);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent1);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(id, notification);
}
```

This is how I getIntentExtras in the ListSongsActivity:

```
private void getIntentExtras() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getIntentExtras()");
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    parsedArtistInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.PARSED_ARTIST_INFO);
    String siteName = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.MUSIC_SITE);
    Log.d(TAG, "getIntentExtras() sitename: " + siteName);
    musicSite = Enum.valueOf(MusicSite.class, siteName);
    Log.d(TAG, "getIntentExtras() artInfo: " + parsedArtistInfo.toString());
}
```

When the ListSongsAtivity is started by the broadcast receiver, the parsedArtistInfo object is the correct object passed by the ParserService, but when ListSongsActivity is opened by notification the parsedArtistInfo object is null.

ArtistInfo class:

```
public class ArtistInfo implements Parcelable {

private static final String TAG = ArtistInfo.class.getSimpleName();

private String url;

private String artist;

// album name to list of ids of songs
private HashMap<String, List<Integer>> albumInfo;

// song id to songInfo
private SparseArray<SongInfo> songsMap;

/**
 * to be used only for ui display logic, don't use for downloading logic
 */
private HashMap<String, Boolean> albumCheckedStatus;

public ArtistInfo() {
}

private ArtistInfo(Parcel in) {
    url = in.readString();
    artist = in.readString();
    // Read album info
    getAlbumInfo();
    int albumInfoSize = in.readInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < albumInfoSize; i++) {
        String key = in.readString();
        List<Integer> value = new ArrayList<>();
        in.readList(value, null);
        albumInfo.put(key, value);
    }

    // Read songs map
    getSongsMap();
    int songsMapSize = in.readInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < songsMapSize; i++) {
        int key = in.readInt();
        SongInfo value = in.readParcelable(SongInfo.class.getClassLoader());
        songsMap.put(key, value);
    }

    getAlbumCheckedStatus();
    int albumCheckStatusSize = in.readInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < albumCheckStatusSize; i++) {
        String key = in.readString();
        Boolean value = in.readByte() != 0;
        albumCheckedStatus.put(key, value);
    }
}

public static final Creator<ArtistInfo> CREATOR = new Creator<ArtistInfo>() {
    @Override
    public ArtistInfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ArtistInfo(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ArtistInfo[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ArtistInfo[size];
    }
};
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(url);
    dest.writeString(artist);
    // Write album info
    getAlbumInfo();
    dest.writeInt(albumInfo.size());
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> item : albumInfo.entrySet()) {
        dest.writeString(item.getKey());
        dest.writeList(item.getValue());
    }

    // Write song map
    getSongsMap();
    dest.writeInt(songsMap.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < songsMap.size(); i++) {
        int key = songsMap.keyAt(i);
        dest.writeInt(key);
        dest.writeParcelable(songsMap.get(key), flags);
    }

    getAlbumCheckedStatus();
    dest.writeInt(albumCheckedStatus.size());
    for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> item : albumCheckedStatus.entrySet()) {
        dest.writeString(item.getKey());
        dest.writeByte((byte) (item.getValue() ? 1 : 0));
    }
}
```

Can someone please point out the error I am making while sending the object in via notification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling `sendNotification()` in your else condition, you are putting bundle to a different `intent`, not to `notifyIntent`. Change your code inside the else like below

```
else {
    // TODO: 10-10-2018 tapping on notification does nothing!!
    Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent(): Sending success notification.");
    String body = "Parsing complete for the url: " + url;
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListSongsActivity.class);
    notifyIntent.putExtra(Constants.MUSIC_SITE, siteName);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(Constants.PARSED_ARTIST_INFO, artistInfo);
    notifyIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    CommonUtils.sendNotification(getApplicationContext(), Constants.LIST_SONGS_NOTIFICATION_TITLE
                            , body, Constants.LIST_SONGS_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, notifyIntent,
                            Constants.LIST_SONGS_NOTIFICATION_ID, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
   }
```

Comment: shit. made a very stupid mistake. thanks. btw can there be a problem in future if the object being passed is somewhat larger than 1MB?

Comment: In that case you will get `TransactionTooLargeException`. Try to keep your object simple. Refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are creating pending intents more than ones in your app. In this case, you should use,

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
```

to create the Intent from scratch and inflate your bundle

Comment: still getting the same error:
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.ks.musicdownloader.activity.common.ArtistInfo.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.ks.musicdownloader.activity.listsongs.ListSongsActivity.getIntentExtras(ListSongsActivity.java:144)
        at com.ks.musicdownloader.activity.listsongs.ListSongsActivity.onCreate(ListSongsActivity.java:81)`

Comment: Man, you are a lifesaver! It helps me when using PendingIntent sms result in SmsManager